# How can I detect the Helper class which I have to use, to narrow my Corba Object?

Tags: java, corba, idl, distributed-transactions, jacorb

My IDL looks like:

```
interface TransactionResource {
    void prepare() raises (NotPreparedException);
    void commit() raises(TransactionException);
    void rollback() raises(TransactionException);
};
interface ManageDemand : TransactionResource {
    string createDemand(in string demand);
};
interface CreateAccount : TransactionResource {
    string createAccount(in string account);
};
```

I create the ManageDemand distributed object on Server , I make it persistent, and it's reachable through the CORBALOC address.

I would like to create a generic method on the client that detects which resource it is ( if it's CreateAccount or manageDemand).

```
public TransactionResource getResource(String url){                    
  Object obj = orb.string_to_object(url.toString());
```

How can I decide this, if I have to use ManageDemandHelper or CreateAccountHelper to narrow this obj?

```
  Ex: ManageDemand transactionResource = ManageDemandHelper.narrow(obj); 

  return transactionResource;                                        
}
```

Comment: I found the response for this problem.
I just have to verify this:
if (obj._is_a("IDL:transaction/ManageDemand:1.0")){
..
} else if (obj._is_a("IDL:transaction/CreateAccount:1.0")){ 
..
}

Comment: You are right. Can you create a answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the response for this problem. I just have to verify this:

if (obj._is_a("IDL:transaction/ManageDemand:1.0")){ .. } else if (obj._is_a("IDL:transaction/CreateAccount:1.0")){ .. }

–  Saad Lamarti Dec 19 '13 at 12:48